If we use Angular rxResource with the Angular Http Client will the Angular build tree shake all unused parts of RxJS?
If we use rxResource with the Angular Http Client (So Observables) will the Angular build tree shake all unused parts of RxJS?

This is totally unrelated to rxResource.
RxJS is built in a way that everything that is unused is removed during optimization.
